# How can I make a list into a dictionary with a common key?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

```
list = ['Roses are red','Sun is shining','cream comes from the bottom']

dict = {'john':'Roses are red', 'john':'Sun is shining','john':'cream comes from the bottom'}
```

I hope I make sense.

Comment: dictionaries doesn't work that way.

Answer (score 6):

you dont ... keys must be unique in dictionaries...

you could do a list of dicts

```
[ {'john':'roses'},{'john':'roses2'},...]
#like this
[ {'john':itm} for itm in my_list ]
```

or a list of tuples/lists

```
[ ('john':'roses'),('john':'roses2'),...]
#like this
[ ('john',itm) for itm in my_list ]
```

or a dict with a list attached to john

```
{'john':[1,2,3]}
#like this
{'john':my_list }
```

Comment: For the third option I would suggest to use a [`defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#defaultdict-examples), to create automatically an empty list for each new key.

Comment: but its only one list ... that is attached to one key ... at least as far as I can tell ... so that makes no sense

Comment: Well, I was assuming the OP was planning to add more keys, otherwise why does he need to replicate the key for each entry?

Comment: I dont know ... he doesnt have any way of selecting a key currently so meh...if thats what he wants he can edit original question to reflect this and show his actual data structures ... assuming he has a different datastructure than the original question portrayed...  but yes if he has many keys and some way of going through them and selecting associated lists a defaultdict would be more appropriat

Answer (score 0):

You can not use the dictionary even if you could do it after wards. If you really want something like that, you could use a list of touples or a list of lists like this

```
[('john','Roses are red'), ('john','Sun is shining'),('john','cream comes from the bottom')]
```

Answer (score 0):

from the [docs](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries):'

> It is best to think of a dictionary as an unordered set of key: value
>   pairs, with the requirement that the keys are unique (within one
>   dictionary)

Answer (score 0):

as said before, keys must be unique... but, you could use the list as the keys:

```
>>> list1 = ['Roses are red','Sun is shining','cream comes from the bottom']
>>> dict1 = { x:'john' for x in list1 }
>>> dict1
>>> {'cream comes from the bottom': 'john', 'Sun is shining': 'john', 'Roses are red': 'john'}
```